# Method return object instead of array

Tags: javascript

I have one question. Why this method return object? In other part of my code i cant use forEach method.

```
objectToArrayOfObjects: function (obj, additionalProperties) {
    var arrayOfObjects = [];
    for (var name in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            var generatedObject = {name: name, value: obj[name]};
            arrayOfObjects.push(_.extend(generatedObject, additionalProperties));
        }
    }
    console.log(typeof arrayOfObjects); // return object
    return arrayOfObjects;
},
```

Comment: `typeof [] === 'object';` because Arrays are essentially Objects in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything inherits from `Object` in Javascript, so `typeof` returns `object`. The method *does* return an array, you can verify that by using: `console.log(arrayOfObjects instanceof Array)`

Comment: Or better - consider the array comming from another frame the above example would be false but looking at the constructors name instead would be ok: `Object.prototype.toString.call(arrayOfObjects) === '[object Array]'`

Comment: Or for that matter `arrayOfObjects.constructor === Array`, or `/array/i.test(arrayOfObjects.constructor)`

Answer (score -1):

you may use $.each method of jquery to loop through the object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also, no need to use jQuery for something that could be accomplished in two lines of code.